# Разделение массива на несколько по три элемента

Tags: delphi, массивы

Помогите, пожалуйста, в решении  задачи, имеется перемешанный массив строк в поле мемо, можно ли сделать так, чтобы первые три элемента шли в один массив, след. три в другой массив и тд, в случае того, что элементы массива не кратны трем, то остаток в последний массив. Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как вам известно, все строки, представленные в Tmemo, это по сути массив, доступ к которому осуществляется через свойство **Strings**:

```
Tmemo.lines.strings[index];
```

Реализовать же разброс этого массива в другие массивы в определенном порядке можно, например, так:

```
...
const m=3;  // количество массивов для разброса
var arr:array[1..m,1..10]of string; // 3 массива по 10 элементов в каждом
counter:integer;
begin
counter := 1;
for i:=0 to Tmemo.lines.count-1 do
begin
arr[counter,last_element]Tmemo.lines.strings[i];
if(i mod 3 = 0)then inc(counter);
if(counter>m) counter:=1;
end;
...
```

Comment: а если кол-во массивов еще не известно ? кол-во массивов должно быть известно только в конце..когда все строки распределяться по массивам..

Comment: В таком случае используйте динамические массивы

        array of string

Answer (score 0):

1. Создать два списка (TList).
2. Объявить вспомогательный счетчик строк и инициализировать его в ноль (Integer).
3. Объявить флажок (Boolean)
4. Для каждой строки из Memo (TMemo.Lines)
5. Если флажок лево, то добавить строку в левый список, если право - в правый.
6. Нарастить счетчик строк.
7. Если счетчик = 3, обнулить его изменить флажок на противоположный.
8. Перекинуть данные из списков в массивы.

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure AddValsToArrays(List: TStrings);
var
  I, CurArrInd: Integer;
  Arrays: array of array of string;
begin
  CurArrInd:= -1;
  for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if I mod 3 = 0 then
      Inc(CurArrInd);
    SetLength(Arrays, CurArrInd + 1);
    SetLength(Arrays[CurArrInd], (I mod 3) + 1);
    Arrays[CurArrInd][I mod 3]:= List[I];
  end;
end;
```